# JSON.parse() not giving expected result

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string that is JSON values separated by /r. It's sort of like records in a DB table. It looks like:

"{"id":"id","hole":"hole","stat":"stat","value":"value"}/r{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"score","value":"4"}/r{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"putts","value":"1"}/r{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"fir","value":"y"}/r{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"gir","value":"n"}/r"

The first row is the column names (id, hole, stat, value) and I just give them the same value. All other rows separated by /r is the actual data.

I split this string by /r, then loop through the result and push the result of JSON.parse() of each element to an array so now I have an array of objects with properties of the given structure (id, hole, stat, value). **Everything is working except the 'id' field ends up being true or false instead of the big long number. Why is it doing that?**

```
var tblData = localStorage.getItem(tblName).split("/r");
var data = new Array();

// fill the array
for (i = 1; i < tblData.length - 1; i++)
    data.push(JSON.parse(tblData[i]));
```

[EDIT]
Seems this does work, but there is a jQuery.grep() I run right after this that's setting the id properties to true/false.

```
var changeRecords = jQuery.grep(data, func);
```

Where func is:

```
function (v) { return v.id == gCurrentRoundID && v.hole == gCurrentHole; }
```

Not sure why it would be setting id to true/false though.

[EDIT2]

Nevermind, I found my error. The function above wasn't the right one and the one I did have only had 1 equal sign for v.id = gCurrentRoundID, which is why it was setting it to true/false.

Comment: it works fine for me. testing in chrome.

Comment: Where did you tested your code? it works in firefox.

Comment: IE 10 on Win 8 box. When I mouse over the id value in Visual Studio it just says true or false.

Comment: Seems to working fine for me too... http://jsfiddle.net/a5EyQ/

Comment: OK, seems this works and the problem is a jQuery.grep() that I run after I fill the array. Updated post but still have the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just manually change the whole string to valid JSON.  Have it start with a `[` and end with a `]`, then replace all those `/r`s with commas.  The end result should look like

> "[{"id":"id","hole":"hole","stat":"stat","value":"value"},{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"score","value":"4"},{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"putts","value":"1"},{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"fir","value":"y"},{"id":1354075540949,"hole":"1","stat":"gir","value":"n"},]"

Then parse *that* through `JSON.parse`

Just note that that last trailing comma may cause problems in IE8.  If so, you should be able to manually fix that fairly easily.  Something like `s = s.substr(0, s.length - 2) + ']';`

Comment: I've never used that syntax before (new to javascript). Would JSON.parse() on the whole thing return an array of objects then ready to go?

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the changes to make things easier on myself then!